# Sharepoint webpartzone change not working

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've created a custom webpart page. When i add webparts on the page it's working fine. But if i change the webpart zone then it's not working. After saving the webpart zone is not changed.

My aspx page:

```
<%@ Page masterpagefile="~masterurl/default.master" language="C#"       Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>


<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
 <WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" id="spwebpartmanager" />
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td  valign="top" width="50%"><WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server"  ID="MainLeft" Title="loc:MainLeft" />
                            &#160;</td>
                        <td  valign="top" width="50%"><WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server"  ID="MainRight" Title="loc:MainRight" />
                         &#160;</td>      
          </tr>
         </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
    <td  valign="top" width="50%">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="MainLeft" Title="loc:MainLeft"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</td>
    <td  valign="top" width="50%">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="MainRight" Title="loc:MainRight"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</td>
</tr>
         </table>
</asp:Content>
```